# How to initialize login functionality in Site.Master form to pull Login ID from SQL after redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms

How do I save results of a logged in user after successful redirect from the Login page or Sign up page? I have a button in the Site.Master parent form, which is loaded with every other web form. I want to get the ID of the logged in user from my SQL database and populate a textbox in a form for Reservation.

My project is in ASP.NET about making room reservations. I have a login in button in the Master Form, which consists of a navigation bar with 8 menu buttons each redirecting to a different Web Page. The data in the Login Form is checked with my SQL server, and upon successful login, the user is redirected to the reservation page. My idea was to declare 2 global variables like a bool, checking if user is logged in on every redirect and an empty string, which gets the value of User ID from SQL if bool LoggedIn is true. But I was unsuccessful in initializing the global variables and calling them in the child form (Booking form) and frankly, I'm not sure if I've taken the right approach to achieving this.
My code in Login_in.aspx.cs for login redirect is the following:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String source = @"Data Source=DESKTOP;Initial Catalog=projectX;Integrated Security=true;";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(source);

            {
                try
                {
                    string uid = TextBox1.Text;
                    string pass = TextBox2.Text;
                    con.Open();
                    string query = "select * from Users where Username='" + uid + "' and Password='" + pass + "'";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("~/Booking.aspx");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Label10.Text = "Wrong pass or username!";
                    }
                    con.Close();

                    Label10.Visible = true;
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

I'm not sure if I have to declare the global variables for bool LoggedIn and string UserID in the Login Form or the Master Form, but I want to change their values upon Response.Redirect("~/Booking.aspx"). If they are declared in the Site.Master.cs file, how can I change their values in the Login form and call them (and their values) in the Booking form. I've tried declaring them as
public static bool LoggedIn = false;
public static string userID;
but wasn't sure how to initialize the get & set properties between forms.

In my Booking form I have a textbox which I want to populate with the username of the loggedIn user by userID (from sql). 
How do I set the properties in the form where the variables are declared and in the forms, where they are called?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Web Forms supports two ways to secure your web application:

- The old one, [Forms Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs)
- The modern, [ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/security/create-a-secure-aspnet-web-forms-app-with-user-registration-email-confirmation-and-password-reset)

They both provide you with the infrastructure to authenticate and authorize users as well as access to the logged in user. They both use a database as storage. Various techniques are used to identify an authenticated user between requests such as cookies.

It is highly recommended that you use either in your application. There are tons of documentation to read about.

On the other hand, implementing your own security system is going to be difficult, error-prone, time consuming, inefficient and ultimately insecure.